# What language is used in this '.format' file

Tags: file, variables, format, comments

I have a piece of code here used in a custom program for developing small assessments called "layout.format":

```
# display assessment time limit
TIMED=<Time_Limit>%SESSION.TIMELIMITMIN%</Time_Limit>
NOTTIMED=<Time_Limit/>

# display randomization key used to generate assessment
PRINT_RANDOM_KEY=%PRINT_RANDOM_KEY_TEXT%
PRINT_NO_RANDOM_KEY=%NO_PRINT_RANDOM_KEY_TEXT%

# page break definitions
PAGEBREAK=

START_PAGE_BREAK=
END_PAGE_BREAK=

# definitions to show answer boxes for different question types
ANSWER_BOX_mc=<input type="radio">
ANSWER_BOX_mr=<input type="checkbox">
ANSWER_BOX_num=<input type="text" size=%CHOICE.WIDTH%>
ANSWER_BOX_tm=<textarea cols="%CHOICE.WIDTH%" rows="%CHOICE.HEIGHT%" >%CHOICE.VALUE%</textarea>
ANSWER_BOX_fib=<input type="text" size=%CHOICE.WIDTH%>
```

I can tell it is using the HTML parts to generate the HTML page for the end user, but just wondered what the main language in the snippet is as I haven't seen this type of Comment or Variable syntax before and would be interesting in editing this file to alter our outcomes.

**EDIT:**
I realise the syntax possibly might not be a language, and could just be used as instructions for a parser of some kind inside the application - but the style makes me believe this is a programming language of some type and if anyone knows what it resembles I would much appreciate knowing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like some kind of configuration file.
And I have not idea which language is it, if at all.

If you want to edit it, or understand how it works, that's what I think about it, the way it works and being parsed:

The `number sign (#)` mentions the comments and every other row is a configuration. I believe the program go through every row which isn't a comment, and split it at the `equal sign (=)`. Later, it replaces the placeholders that are surrounded with `percentage (%)` like `%SESSION.TIMELIMITMIN%` or `%CHOICE.WIDTH%` with dynamic values that are given at run time or taken from somewhere. And finally, inject those tags in some kind of xml/html format.

Following the rest of your code you should be able to understand what it's doing, how it being used and when. Try to see if your program parses the file, uses external library or something else. It will give you much more information about the file.

Comment: You make good, valid points there. I'll take your advice and do some experimenting and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait in replying. Just wanted to let you know you were bang-on so thank you for taking the time to explain your thinking to a newbie at the time :)

Comment: Glad it could help!